# Using std::make_pair in map initializer list

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list

Is there a difference in the following initializations of a static map?

```
static std::map<FunctionID, std::string> enum_string_representation {
  {FunctionID.something, "something"}
};
```

and

```
static std::map<FunctionID, std::string> enum_string_representation {
  {std::make_pair(FunctionID.something, "something")}
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No difference. There are several possible [constructors of map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/map) and you are using this one in both cases:

```
map( std::initializer_list<value_type> init,
     const Compare& comp = Compare(),
     const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

`value_type` is of `type std::pair<..,..>` and built from either `{FunctionID.something, "something"}` or `std::make_pair(FunctionID.something, "something")`.

You could also write:

```
static std::map<FunctionID, std::string> enum_string_representation {
  std::make_pair(FunctionID.something, "something")
};
```